# Persistent php data collections

Tags: php

Writing an api using routes similar to Laravel.  Right now I am reloading the routes, controllers, methods with each request.  Obviously this is very dumb, but I can't find a way to be able to read in the persistent data one time and keep it in between requests.

tl;dr: How do I keep route collections around between requests to prevent multiple collection adds every request.  Would like to just grab the collection with each new request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. Cache the data. There are plenty of tools to achieve this. I'm personally using [redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).
2. Cache some of the bytecode created from your code with tools like [OPcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

You should only try to cache the data. Caching bytecode is in the most cases not needed. I know that you think, that interpreting all that code will consume much time, but don't care too much. PHP is good in doing that. It's mostly less than `100 ms`.

Comment: So me adding routes to the route collection with every request does not matter much? Albeit, I have not noticed it to be slow from a user's perspective. Coming from a strong C++ background, it just feels very dirty and inefficient.

Comment: That's how PHP works. It's an _interpreted language_. It interprets the code on each call. It uses internally some good algorithms to make it fast as possible, also some caching stuff.